# Expressing fact in polynomial size boolean expression

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, reduction

If I have boolean variables a_1, a_2, .. , a_n. How can I express the fact that number of boolean variables which are set to true is bigger than some k, using polynomial size boolean expression? (Exponential is easy - just write newton(n,k) expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort your booleans with any sorting network. Then just take (k+1)'th sorted bit, which gives you the result.

Since each of the sorting network's elements represents a pair of logical operations, you can interpret this network as logical expression. With good sorting network, this will give you an expression with O(N*log<sup>2</sup>(N)) operations.

Comment: That's it! I just failed to specify, that I need this expression in CNF (Still polynomial). Can you think of an example of a sorting network, that will allow me to have that reasonably simply?

Comment: CNF makes this problem much more difficult. I don't know any sorting network which gives CNF expression. And, as far as I know, transforming any expression to CNF can lead to an exponential explosion of the expression in worst case. I don't know any solution which is both CNF and polynomial. Most likely this is impossible.

Comment: Well, that is simply not true. Most of the expersions that human come up, by hand are transformable to CNF, also every turing machine can be written as CNF expression in polynomial complexity, so if we take a machine that does sorting, we would have transform in polynomial complexity. All I am asking for is the sorting network for which it is easy, to write that out by hand, so that proof is kept simple.

Comment: Every known sorting network produces expressions of the same form: alternating ANDs and ORs. So expression from any network will be equally simple (or equally impossible) to transform to CNF. I cannot recommend any particular one. If choosing simple network with small number of operations, try [Batcher odd–even mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort) or [Bitonic sorter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter). Still I'm thinking about the proof why CNF cannot be polynomial.

Comment: Ok, but the fact that "most of the sorting networks you know" happen to be expressible such a sat expressions that only have exponential sized canonical representation, doesn't prove that all the sorting networks will have exponential sized normal form, does it? Besides, I actually found polynomial 3-CNF expression that is equivalent to clique (which was my original problem), I am not sure what the exact definition of sorting network is, but I am quite sure subset of my expression could be use to write polynomial size 3-CNF sorting network.

Comment: I don't insist that all the sorting networks will have exponential sized normal form. Actually, my yesterday's "proof" doesn't look convincing. But I'm still not sure if polynomial CNF is possible for your case. And if it is possible, I don't know what's easier: transform some sorting network's expression to CNF or just simplify the solution from OP. The expression from your today's post doesn't look either 3-CNF or just CNF.

Answer (score 0):

let t[i][j] mean that out of elements a_1, .., a_i, j of them is set to true. 
Now we can clearly see that

```
    t[i][j] => (t[i-1][j] or (t[i-1][j-1] and a_i).
```

(as either variable was already set in a_1, .., a_(i-1) or a_i is set and there is j-1 variables in a_1, .. , a_(i-1).
This is polynomial size expression (around n*k variables t[i][j], for each one expression like the one I have written above). Then if t[n][k] is true, we get that our of n variables at least k is true.

Reffering to Evgeny answer,
To get the variables in the sorted order (first trues, then falses), we look at the sequence
t[n][1], t[n][2], .. t[n][n].